# DAE with NDSolve -monitor numerical noise

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I have a very 2d non-linear differential algebraic equation I'm trying to solve with NDSolve.

The solution seems fine, but There are some numerical issues I cannot manage to control, and I don't know how to approach it.

Here is the example

```
f[x_, z_] := ((20 z)/(1 - Exp[-20 x z])/(
     1 + (20 z)/(1 - Exp[-20 x z])) - (20 z Exp[-20 x z])/(
     1 - Exp[-20 x z])/(
     1 + (20 z Exp[-20 x z])/(1 - Exp[-20 x z]))) - z; 
f[x_, y_, z_] := z - 0.1 (x - 1) (1 + 1/(4 y) Exp[(x - 1)/(5 y)]); 
g[x_, y_] := 1 - y - y Exp[(x - 1)/(5 y)];

sol = NDSolve[{
    f[x[t], z[t]] == 0,
    x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t], z[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], x[0] == 1.9,
     y[0] == 0.9}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
       "SimplifySystem" -> True}}];

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], 
  Evaluate[z[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x(t)", "y(t)", "z(t)"}, {Right, Top}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["t", FontSize -> 14, Black], ""}]

Plot[{Evaluate[z[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"z(t)"}, {Right, Top}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["t", FontSize -> 14, Black], ""}]
```

When I plot the three functions together, the solution seems fine. however when I plot $z(t)$ by itself, you can see that there is always noise.

[image]

[image]
How can I add a fixed step to the solution of the DAE, or somehow monitor that what that I'm doing is correct?

Comment: Try `PlotRange->All` for the `z` plot.

Comment: @user21, It's still noisy, The solution is expected to converge smoothly to the constant value.

Comment: have you noticed that the y-range doesn't even give an indication of the size of the noise? To me it looks like that could well be within the expected numeric precision...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, is there I way I can verify that?

Comment: Well, then use `PlotRange -> {0.94, 0.96}`.

Comment: Use `MinMax[Table[Evaluate[z[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10, 0.01}]]` to verify.

Comment: @User21, please explain what is the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @jarhead, Mathematica does the right thing. It selects the interesting part of the data - Up to machine precision. This is expected numerical noise.

Comment: @User21, it is flat, i.e, {0.95,0.95}, does that mean there is no numeric error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is well in the acceptable numerical noise regime:

```
Subtract @@ MinMax[Table[Evaluate[z[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10, 0.01}]]
-3.606067700001603`*^-8
```

Set the `NDSolve` options

```
, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12
```

to lower this if you think it is too much.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the numerical noise is not the issue here.

Comment: @jarhead, No, I do not think so. It is just Plot that tries hard to show some action in the data. I would not worry about it.